# Unable to attach to remote geth: Timed out waiting for pipe '\\.\pipe\geth.ipc' to come available

Tags: ethereum

I run this command **geth attach ipc:\.\pipe\geth.ipc** show the this type of message

```
Unable to attach to remote geth: Timed out waiting for pipe '\\.\pipe\geth.ipc' to come available
```

Please could you suggest me. I,m newbie.

Answer (score 0):

In which environment you are trying to achieve it?
If it is windows try

```
geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

Also, make sure IPC is not disabled **--ipcdisable** flag.
If you are running multiple geth's in one environment ,disable ipc of all the geth node's except the one you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

While running the geth node itself, specify the ipcpath. It will open the geth node, ipc and javascript console for you in single window. Try the below command.

```
geth --datadir ../../private-network/node1 \
      --networkid 2061 \(it should be same, if you are running multiple nodes)
      --port 30304 \ (should be different for every nodes)
      --nodiscover \
      --rpc \
      --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 \
      --rpcport 8504 \ (should be different for every nodes)
      --ipcpath ../../private-network/node1/geth.ipc \
      --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" \
      --etherbase 0xf628e41f3ca68341e9857102d4b3040aa418d763 \ (your coinbase account address)
      --verbosity 3 console
```

> One example for the given script.

```
geth --datadir=D:/Blockchain_Tech/node1 --networkid 2061 --port 30305 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8505 --ipcpath=D:/Blockchain_Tech/node1/geth.ipc --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" --etherbase 0x58ef18d5667552b4c0524b9a78cbf9493d2bd74a --verbosity 3 console
```

> Note:- This script is for MS-Windows.